# New .aspx page in Visual Studio Web Application crashes page

Tags: asp.net

i'm having a WebPart for displaying information about employees and i want to display only a view information about the persons. The rest should be available after clicken on a "more" link. I tried to get that with opening a "popup"window.
But i don't get that to work right. So i tried using a new page. Hence i added a new aspx page to my project in visual studio 
and added a link to that page like that:

LinkButton link = new LinkButton(); link.Width = Unit.Pixel(20);
link.Text = "more";

After building the project i tested it in my webpart page and get an error
"An unexpected error occured".

It took me a lot to get the webpart work properly again.

Has anybody an idea what i'm doing wrong. (i also tried to catch an exception without success)

I also tried to add an click event to that "more" link. but then, when i hover above that link with the mouse i see
"javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$m$g_84d91faf_d0a8_4587_bb7c_712030d2c4ea$ctl00$ctl18','')"
i tried with link.OnClientClick and link.OnClick, nothing works.

I really need that function for that page.
I would highly appreciate it if you can give me a code snippet of a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: may be I am not able to understand your question properly. if yes let me know

Answer (score 0):

You should use `PostBackUrl` property of linkbutton Or on button click event you can call  `Response.Redirect`

Comment: Could you please explain me with an Example?